# Python list comparison differences

Tags: python, list

I have seen methods for list comparison on stackoverflow before, but they all seem to return the matches for a list - not the non matches. I am interested to find the method that returns the non matching values (and possibly which list they came from).

```
listA = ['spanish', 'english', 'chinese', 'italian', 'english']
listB = ['spanish', 'english', 'italian', 'japanese']
```

I would like to return at least which words were NOT found in bouth;

```
['chinese','japanese']
```

If not this;

```
[('chinese',listA),('japanese',listB)]
```

Please offer any solutions for this comparison method(s).

Comment: Show us the Python code you have tried to achieve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`set.symmetric_difference`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.symmetric_difference) for this:

```
>>> set(listA).symmetric_difference(listB)
set(['japanese', 'chinese'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set) for this:

```
>>> listA = ['spanish', 'english', 'chinese', 'italian', 'english']
>>> listB = ['spanish', 'english', 'italian', 'japanese']
>>> list(set(listA) ^ set(listB))  # Note that the results will be unordered
['japanese', 'chinese']
>>>
```

The `^` operator finds the symmetric difference between the two sets.

Answer (score 1):

In other words this is what you are looking for: `set(listA) - set(listB) | set(listB) - set(listA)`

```
>>> listA = ['spanish', 'english', 'chinese', 'italian', 'english']
>>> listB = ['spanish', 'english', 'italian', 'japanese']
>>> setA = set(listA)
>>> setB = set(listB)
>>> setA - setB | setB - setA
set(['japanese', 'chinese'])
>>>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the answer displays a lack of knowledge about `set1.symmetric_difference(set2)` also known as `set1 ^ set2`.

Comment: Agreed this may be inefficient. Is it wrong though?

Comment: An answer doesn't have to be wrong to be a bad answer.  Upon further consideration, I also downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution, which does not involve `set()`:

```
 >>> from collections import Counter
 >>> [v for v, k in Counter(listA + listB).iteritems() if k==1]
 ['japanese', 'chinese']
```